# Write a pattern after values of dataframe which follow a specific condition in another dataframe

Tags: r

I get two dataframes with the same number of rows and columns. I'd like to create a third one where I'll put all the values of the second dataframe (df2) and a pattern (*) after those values if the values at the same position in the first dataframe (df1) are less than 0.050.

Below the script of the two dataframes followed by the expected dataframe in the image. 
I found no means to do that, except manually. Thanks for your help!

```
set.seed(123)
df1=matrix(data = rnorm(12, .06, .03), nrow = 4, ncol = 3); colnames(df1)=c("a", "b","c")
set.seed(123)
df2=matrix(data = rnorm(12, .5, .1), nrow = 4, ncol = 3); colnames(df2)=c("a", "b","c")
```

[expected dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgHUQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a logical matrix based on 'df1', assign the values in 'df3' that corresponds to the logical index by `paste`ing the '*' at the end

```
df3 <- df2
i1 <- df1 < 0.05
df3[i1] <- paste(df3[i1], "*")
```